# .htaccess catch GET parameters in any order

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Im trying to write a rewrite rule that checks if multiple get paramaters are set in any order and then redirect to a url using the arguments from these get parameters this is what I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)retailer_filter=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)product=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)sitechange=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /?product=%1&retailer_filter=%2 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects but only has the sitechange argument so

`/?product=test&retailer_filter=test&sitechange=1` redirects to `?/product=1&retailer_filter=`

when I want it to redirect `?/product=test&retailer_filter=test`

but it needs to be able to accept the get parameters in differen orders so

`/?sitechange=1t&retailer_filter=test&product=test` would also need to redirect to `?/product=test&retailer_filter=test`

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively trying to delete `sitechange` query parameter. You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?sitechange=[^&]*&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This rule will accept GET parameters in any order. `sitechange=` can be at first or last or in middle position.